# How to Append java codes in JSP using JQuery

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

I am working with JSP pages and I need to `.append()` into a `DIV` element some java codes.

```
$("#myDiv").append("<% out.println("ali"); %>");
```

The previous code is actually wrong because there's quotes, so I escaped them.

```
$("#myDiv").append("<% out.println(\"ali\"); %>");
```

But I wasn't successful, nothing was appended to `#myDiv`

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, it sounds that jQuery is not loaded correctly or there is another problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/5PTwN/1/

Comment: It worked, but the problem is that it is being displayed as :
<% out.println(\"ali\"); %>
rather than just , ali , the java codes aren't being executed

Comment: @AliBassam you cannot parse Java or other serverside languages codes using jQuery, you are appending just a string.

Comment: BUT I JUST CAN'T UNDERSTAND THE CONCEPT OF AJAX AND SERVLETS :(
 my goal is to append something like this [ <% while(true) { %> <dive>la</div> <% } %> ] , I can put this in the jsp page but I only want this thing to be appended when I click on some button, means I need to use click function in jquery, help please :(

Comment: @AliBassam As the code should be rendered via server, your only option is Ajax, you can read jQuery documentation  which is a great source for starting using it. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#myDiv").append('<% out.print("ali"); %>');
```

below line also should work because java code will execute server side and inside append will be replaced with "ali".

```
$("#myDiv").append("<% out.print("ali"); %>");
```

Comment: Check whether it is jsp file or not and if it is jsp how your are testing this

Answer (score 0):

This is correct way to append. If nothing is appended, then the div might not exists in the page.

Try using firebug and check what6 is the output of console.log($('#muDiv'))